# C - can variate location be promoted?

Tags: c, function, loops, pointers, memory-address

I am new to the language and was trying a simple code. I wanted to try to create a loop based on pointers. but it seems like you can not promote variate location like in assembler. or i just did it wrong? and if i really can't can i force a new variadate to be born in specific location? that was my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int firstnumber = 1;
    int *beginning = &firstnumber;
    printf("%i %i \n",firstnumber,beginning);
    Test1(firstnumber,beginning);
    return 0;
}

Test1 (int num, int begin)
{
    int reserve = num;
    if(num != 100)
    {
        &num +=2;
        num = (reserve+1);
        return Test1(num, begin);

    }
    else
    {
        int assist = begin;
        while(*assist != 100)
        {
            printf("/n \n %i %i \n /n",num,assist);
            &assist += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

I know it might look ridiculous but i'm really curious

Comment: "Variate"? "Variadate"? Not sure what you mean by "promote" either, it has a specific meaning in C which makes it confusing.

Comment: You should declare the prototype of `Test1` before using it: `void Test1 (int num, int begin);`

Comment: What is `Test1` supposed to do ? What output do you expect?

Comment: 1 to 100 loop with each number memory adress

Comment: And sorry for confusing you guys. i learned assembler several years ago and was told that C if very efficient and powerful language. i just wanted to see what i can do in here. i will take that guy Martin advice and check about packed struct. i would rep you guys if i could i just don't have an access. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about this backwards. Pointers are the variables you can move around, so use them for anything you want to move around.

`firstnumber` is an integer variable - the compiler decides where it is stored and you can't tell the compiler to rebind the name `firstnumber` to a different location. You can, however, move a *pointer* around as much as you like. So,

```
void Test1(int num) {
    &num +=2;
    num = 42;
}
```

is nonsense, but

```
void Test2(int *num) {
    num += 2;
    *num = 42;
}
```

is fine - *so long as* `num+2` is still a valid allocated object. For example, you could call it like

```
int i[5];
Test2(i); /* sets i[2] = 42 */
```

(if you pass in an array of fewer than 3 integers you get a runtime bug rather than a compile error, as `Test2` damages your stack frame or other memory it shouldn't be touching).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot promote/change variable location.

So this:

```
int num;
&num +=2;
```

does not make sense, and will result in an error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
         &num +=2;
              ^~
```

Same for:

```
int assist;
&assist += 2;
```

Your code will compile only if you modify these statements (but now the logic is changed, you should work on that), but now it will result in an infinite loop, since your function *never returns* in the `else` case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Test1 (int num, int* begin);

int main(void) {
    int firstnumber = 1;
    int *beginning = &firstnumber;
    printf("%i %i \n",firstnumber, *beginning);
    Test1(firstnumber, beginning);
    return 0;
}

void Test1 (int num, int* begin)
{
    int reserve = num;
    if(num != 100)
    {
        num +=2;
        num = reserve + 1;
        return Test1(num, begin);

    }
    else
    {
        int assist = *begin;
        while(assist != 100)
        {
            printf("/n \n %i %i \n /n",num,assist);
            assist += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. can i at least make new variate be born in specific location? (like immediatley after specific diffrent variate?)

Comment: Declare them in a packed struct.

Answer (score 0):

OK i checked the code deeper and got several conclusions:

function variable can not inherit his ancestor adress. therefore using a function for the task is useless unless i use some static variable

I had another conclusion but i don't remember what it was. sorry and thank you for your time